# use scholar.google.com reference in latex file

Tags: latex

When I use scholar.google.com to get the full reference code (BibTeX) such as

```
@article{li2018design,
  title={Design and implementation of building structure monitoring system based on radio frequency identification (RFID)},
  author={Li, Hongwei and Ren, Yilei},
  journal={International Journal of RF Technologies},
  volume={9},
  number={1-2},
  pages={37--49},
  year={2018},
  publisher={IOS Press}
}
```

Then go to the journal template file, I want to copy the reference from scholar.google.com and paste it into the LaTex journal template file without doing any modification.

The template file looks like this:
[image: Example]

Unfortunately, the paste in the template file does NOT work.
Here is the error message:
[image: Error Message]

Can you assist of how to do it and make the file work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format given by Google scholar has to be used when you compile, in order, with

- Latex (or PDFLatex)
- Bibtex
- Latex (or PDFLatex)
- Latex (or PDFLatex)

where you store the entries of your bibliography in a separate file named `<mydoc>.bib`.

You are simply using `\thebibliography` environment, which allows you to write `\bibitem`s, which is a simpler approach (even if I suggest to use it when you have a small number of bibliography entries). If you have to use this latter approach, you have to rewrite the reference retrieved in Google scholar in the format needed by your document.

Have a look [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_bibtex?nocdn=true): it explains very well the differences.